# File doesn't save on first try

Tags: android, file, picasso, android-external-storage

When I run my app for the first time files aren't created but when I call the method again it works.

This is when I call to refresh:

```
List<Product> prod = new Select().from(Product.class).queryList();
for (Product products:prod){
    ImageCache  imageCache = new ImageCache();
    Log.i("product", products.getProductDescr());
    imageCache.setProductName(products.getProductName());
    Picasso.with(this)
           .load(products.getProductImage())
           .into(imageCache.getTarget());
}
```

And this is the class that I call with the method:

```
public class ImageCache {

public  String productName;

public void setProductName(String productName) {
    this.productName = productName;
}

public String getProductName() {
    return productName;
}

public Target getTarget() {
    return target;
}

public void setTarget(Target target) {
    this.target = target;
}

public  Target target = new Target() {
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {



                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +"/Thesis/" +productName+ ".jpg");
                try
                {
                    file.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, ostream);
                    ostream.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }).start();
    }
    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
        if (placeHolderDrawable != null) {
        }
    }
};}
```

SOLUTION:
When target is created must hold a strong reference to avoid garbage collection. This will be succeeded with this example

```
public class MyClass {
   private Target mTarget = new Target() {...};

  public void getPointMarkerFromUrl(final String url, final OnBitmapDescriptorRetrievedListener listener) {

     Picasso.with(context)
     .load(url)
     .resize(maxSize, maxSize)
     .into(mTarget);
   }
}
```

Comment: Print your exception (e.printStackTrace()) to see what is the error.

Comment: e.printStackTrace() doesn't show anything because the problem isn't there. The first time it doesn't call the method `.into(imageCache.getTarget())`  and thats why it doesn't create the files!Second time though everything is alright